# start.command permission denied even after chmod

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I have been trying to run my server.command file forever. I have tried changing access privileges with `chmod x+u` pressing enter then dragging the file into Terminal and pressing enter, but when I do, it says:

> -bash: /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command: Permission denied

Comment: Despite `chmod x+u` being incorrect as discussed in the answers provided, you also seem to be missing the fundamentals of what you're trying to accomplish, because you're pressing enter to run the command immediately after `chmod x+u`, but you should be pressing space instead, then inserting the file path, so that the chmod has a path to execute upon.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually used `chmod x+u filename` then here is the results of a sample from Terminal:

```
$ echo 'echo Hello World!' > hello.command
$ ls -l hello.command
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  18 Aug  5 14:24 hello.command
$ chmod x+u hello.command
chmod: Invalid file mode: x+u
$ ./hello.command
-bash: ./hello.command: Permission denied
$ chmod +x hello.command
$ ls -l hello.command
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  18 Aug  5 14:24 hello.command
$ ./hello.command
Hello World!
$
```

It just needs to be: `chmod +x filename`

If you only want it executable for the User, then use: `chmod u+x filename`

Comment: still says: -bash: /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command: Permission denied

Comment: @Kipperbang12, What is the output from Terminal of `ls -l filename` where `filename` is the name of the file (including path if necessary)?

Comment: this everything i typed: Last login: Wed Aug  5 19:29:46 on ttys000
Alecs-Air:~ Alec$ chmod +x
usage: chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
 chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...
Alecs-Air:~ Alec$ /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command
-bash: /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command: Permission denied

Comment: i don't know what you mean by '1s'?

Comment: Copy and paste the following command into a Terminal and then press Enter and then copy and paste the output back here to a comment: `ls -l /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command`

Comment: ls -l /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command -bash
ls: -bash: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 Alec  staff  82  5 Aug 18:35 /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command

Comment: @Kipperbang12, Sorry try again, I edited my last comment to remove what shouldn't have been then from my copy and paste.  However it looks like it has not been set executable... so do as I instructed in my answer.

Comment: @Kipperbang12 The "Usage" message that `chmod` printed is telling you that you didn't use the command correctly, and offering a hint about how to use it correctly; specifically, you didn't tell it what file to modify. Try `chmod +x /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

```
chmod u+x <filename>
```

rather than:

```
chmod x+u <filename>
```

So try:

```
chmod u+x /Users/Alec/Desktop/Tekkit_Server_v1.2.9g/start.command
```

Comment: Updated with command they could try...

Comment: The u would be necessary if you only wanted the file to be executable for the owner.